# Mapping outside quaternions to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I'm trying to map rotations from a sensor into Unity using Quaternions, and I cannot 
seem to figure out why rotations do not map correctly.

I'm using the [Adafruit BNO055](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor?view=all) to pull absolute orientation in the form of Quaternions. The 
source for their Quaternion implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BNO055/blob/master/utility/quaternion.h). From what I understand about 
Quaternions, which is almost nothing, I should be able to pull a Quaternion out of the sensor and 
pump it into any GameObject inside Unity so that they share the same orientation. If I had a loop 
set up that read the Quaternion data from the sensor and pumped it into Unity, the GameObject should 
rotate exactly like the sensor in the physical world. Unfortunately, this is not happening.

An example of the data sent from the sensor to Unity

```
w: 0.903564
x: 0.012207
y: 0.009094
z: -0.428223
```

Is the Quaternion sent from the sensor not equal to the Quaternions used in Unity? If not, how 
would I go about getting these mapped correctly?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Unit quaternions are pulled out of the sensor. there is no special type of quaternion. check your rotation logic.(ex, applying them with quaternion multiplication)

Comment: @JinbomHeo Could you elaborate a little more on the check your rotaion logic? I'm basically saying object.rotation = new Quaternion(w, x, y, z)

Comment: Unity quaternion's constructor is new Quaternion(x, y, z, w), not w,x,y,z. And there could be relative rotation values. if it's the case you should be object.rotation = object.rotation * new Quaternion(x, y, z, w).

Comment: Yeah, that was just a generic constructor example, not verbatim Unitys. Thanks, I'll try multiplying by that and see what I get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just for example of diffrent conversions (including Unity and OpenGL)
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/coordinate-systems

I don't know your device and coordinates notation, but you can recover it making some experiments with orientation.

The main problem of conversion, that conversion matrix may contain MIRRORING (-1 matrix component). And can't be solved just rearanging rotation axes.

Comment: This answer is now pretty useless because it requires the link to be valid, and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

When I have created a Quaternion from an external sensor in a comma separated list, this works for me:

```
parts = SensorReceivedText.Split(',');
float x = Convert.ToSingle(parts[0]);
float y = Convert.ToSingle(parts[1]);
float z = Convert.ToSingle(parts[2]);
float w = Convert.ToSingle(parts[3]);
Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion(x, y, z, w);
```

Comment: Creating the Quaternion I don't have a problem with, it is ensuring the quaternions match.

Comment: I was just making sure you weren't losing precision with conversion.