# Android quaternions to Unity3D quaternions

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I'm trying to make an Unity3D application for PC that receives via bluetooth the quaternions obtained by my Android with the [getQuaternionFromVector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getQuaternionFromVector(float[],%20float[])) and I wanted to rotate a Cube in Unity with those same quaternions, but for some reason doing simply Quaternion(x,y,z,w) isn't working as expected.

If I rotate my cellphone in his Y or X separately it works, but Z seems inverted and if first I make a rotation in X axis and then another one in Z, Unity makes the Z rotation in the camera perspective (axis) and not of the cube.

[image]

After suspecting that I wanted to use local rotations I changed from `cube.transform.Rotation = delta;` to `cube.transform.localRotation = delta;` but the problem continues.

Actually I have the code in my Update function like this (where `initialRotation` is the first quaternion of my cellphone):

```
  Quaternion transQuat = Quaternion.identity;
            transQuat.x = (float)quaternion[1];
            transQuat.y = (float)quaternion[2];
            transQuat.z = (float)quaternion[3];
            transQuat.w = (float)quaternion[0];

            Quaternion delta = jointRotation * Quaternion.Inverse(initialRotation);

            cube.transform.localRotation = delta;
```

I've found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982459/mapping-outside-quaternions-to-unity) but I didn't understand what was his solution.

So how can I make the quaternion rotations in Unity happen in local rotations to the cube?

Comment: Use this link https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/coordinate-systems

and phrase from article "Project Tango's DEVICE coordinate frame is the same as the Android Sensor Coordinate System"

and than "Converting Project Tango Pose data into the Unity Coordinate System"

Comment: @minorlogic Thanks for the help, I ended up searching arround that link and found out this: https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/project-tango#8

But it seems now it's even wrost and since they use position I removed that. So how do I multiply matrix to quaternions in Unity? And The problem continues the same, they rotate the axis allways in camera perspective and not in cube, I want local rotations in Cube.

Comment: Have you tried using the Euler Angles members instead of trying to manipulate the quaternion directly?  This way you can do your own coordinate transforms and make sure everything ends up in the right place.

Comment: @NotAGenie that was my initial experiment but quickly I understood that they are limit and even if I convert from quaternions to Euler wouldn't I get the problem of a Gimbal lock?

I want to use sensors to capture dancing movements so it's important that I don't limit much the movements.